# Is there a trustworthy ranking of quantitative finance degrees?

Tags: research

I'm interested to know if there is a trustworthy ranking of master's degree in quantitative finance.

I'm specifically interested in some recruiter's perspective or experience, if available.

I ask because I would like to join next year the master's degree in quantitative finance in [ETH Zurich](https://www.ethz.ch/en.html), so if you have any opinion on that specific university it would be great!

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have not used them in regards to Master's Degree studies for myself. www.quantnet.com seems to have a pretty good site for such information.  They also have a forum that is pretty active where you can ask questions you may have about quantitative studies as well as school rankings.